# How to find the #fragment in a URL in Lift

Tags: scala, lift

I'm pretty new to Lift, and one of the things I've been trying to find is how to, in the context of a snippet, find the '#' in the current page's URL. So if a user visits `http://www.example.com/some/path/page#stuff` then I would like to extract "stuff" from that. I've been googling and searching the API docs and have yet to find anything for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the part behind the `#` ever gets sent to the server in the first place.

That's what [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) has to say about it:

> In URIs a hashmark # introduces the
>   optional fragment near the end of the
>   URL. The generic RFC 3986 syntax for
>   URIs also allows an optional query
>   part introduced by a question mark ?.
>   In URIs with a query and a fragment
>   the fragment follows the query. Query
>   parts depend on the URI scheme and are
>   evaluated by the server — e.g., http:
>   supports queries unlike ftp:.
>   Fragments depend on the document MIME
>   type and are evaluated by the client
>   (Web-browser). Clients are not
>   supposed to send URI-fragments to
>   servers when they retrieve a document,
>   and without help from a local
>   application (see below) fragments do
>   not participate in HTTP redirections.

Comment: Yes, hashtags never send to server by browser. You should use them on client side with JavaScript.

Comment: Ok well that answers that.. is there any way (ajax-related maybe?) that I could get that from the client into the Lift side of my app?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't think the part behind the #
>   ever gets sent to the server in the
>   first place.

You are correct, sir.  That is the entire point of the hash.

Dylan, you could do something from the Javascript side:

```
$.ajax( {   data : { fragment : window.location.hash ...
```